# Remove footer on title page or change content frame size

Tags: vertical-alignment, titles

How can I change the size of the content frame to align it to the footer line? The distance between `TEXT3` and the bottom page edge should be the same as the distance between `TEXT1` and the top page edge.

I want to do this just on the title page.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
TEXT1
\vfill
TEXT2
\vfill
TEXT3
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Or: Where is the problem with an empty footer line? Add this information to your question or enhance the minimal example.

Comment: I removed the [tag:koma-script] tag because the behaviour also shows up with standard classes.

Answer (score 3):

As your closing text ("TEXT3") doesn't contain any characters that descend below the baseline, add a `\strut` to correct the vertical alignment.

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
TEXT1
\vfill
TEXT2
\vfill
TEXT3\strut
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```